# Matplotlib - ticks direction for a plot in logarithmic scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot ticks markers inside of the layout. But since an update of Python, these markers are plotted outside... I try to add "ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(direction = 'in')" in my script. It works only for major values.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.loglog(testI[:],a[:],'b+',linewidth=2,label='a');

plt.loglog(testI[:],b[:],'y+',linewidth=2,label='b');

plt.xlim(6,45)
plt.ylim(10**(-7),19**(-1))

ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(direction = 'in')
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(direction = 'in')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`set_tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_tick_params.html?highlight=set_tick_params#matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_tick_params) method takes a keyword argument `which` that defaults to `'major'`. You want to pass `'both'` to also include the minor ticks.

Example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
(figure, axes) = pyplot.subplots()
axes.loglog([], [])
axes.set_xlim(1,100)
axes.set_ylim(1,100)
axes.xaxis.set_tick_params(direction='in', which='both')
axes.yaxis.set_tick_params(direction='in', which='both')
pyplot.show()
```

You could also use [`axes.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params) in that example to configure both axes in one call.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for you help :) jerome